# C++ memory stack/register scope

Tags: c++

I have the following code.

```
void setCoin() {
    int coin;
    int tmpC = 0;
    int tmpA = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < GRPS.size(); i++) {
        coin = workerCoin();
        GRPS[i].choice = coin;

        //printf("\n| group: %d |%d|", GRPS[i].size, coin);
        if(coin) {
            tmpC += GRPS[i].size;
        }
        else {
            tmpA += GRPS[i].size;
        }
    }
    cheaters = tmpC;
    altruistic = tmpA;
    grp = GRPS[GRPS.size() / 2];
}
```

where **cheaters & altruistic** have a global scope within the file, and **tempC & tmpA** have local scope within the setCoin() function.

Would tmpC & tmpA be loaded-onto/treated-as registers even when the code goes into a `for` loop?

I ask this because the `for` loop creates a local variable, `i`, hence tmpC & tmpA may no longer be "local" within the scope of the for loop. Would changing this `for` loop into a `while` loop fix this and have tmpC & tmpA loaded-onto/treated-as registers?

Comment: Why exactly do you care about registers?

Comment: I recently learned about optimization when compiling, and when code is converted into assembly it treats local variables as registers. A mini project I'm working on repeatedly uses this function, and I wanted to make this efficient as possible with respect to time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot know for sure, you have to compile it and then disassemble to find out if registers are used or not. The type of loop doesn't matter, though.

Comment: And don't forget to compile it with optimizations enabled if you are going to check.

Answer (score 1):

> Would tmpC & tmpA be loaded-onto/treated-as registers even when the code goes into a `for` loop?

It doesn't make any difference about the 'for' loop.

> I ask this because the `for` loop creates a local variable, i, hence tmpC & tmpA may no longer be "local" within the scope of the `for` loop.

Irrelevant.

> Would changing this for loop into a while loop fix this and have tmpC & tmpA loaded-onto/treated-as registers?

There is nothing to fix. The optimizer will or won't put tmpA/tmpC into registers according to its own rules, which don't relate to the existence or absence of inner scopes.

Answer (score 0):

The question is essentially irrelevant because the accumulator variables *must* be declared/initialized outside the for loop and they are used inside it. There is nothing you can change, and a `while` will make no difference.

But you needn't worry. An optimizing compiler is quite able to deal with variable lifetime and optimize the allocation to memory vs. registers.

In the case of the given snippet, no doubt that the accumulators will be kept in registers, unless the register stack is fully busy.